# "count not find declaration file for module" in plain Javacript?

Tags: javascript, eclipse

I know this is a recurrent one, but in a plain js project ?

I'm not using Typescript in one of my projects, but I'm still getting `count not find declaration file for module` in Eclipse when I import geoplug in module. Specifically in this line:

```
import { getGeo } from 'geoplugin';
```

It's a React/Redux frontend. There isn't a @types/geoplugin package. How can I get rid of this error ?

Please notice that the error is reported on Eclipse only.

**Edit**

My package.json is this:

```
{
  "name": "myproj",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.6.1",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.1",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "clientjs": "^0.2.1",
    "date-fns": "^2.12.0",
    "geoplugin": "^1.0.10",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "react": "^17",
    "react-dom": "^17",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "^4",
    "sass": "^1.49.0",
    "semantic-ui-css": "^2.4.1",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^2.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "cp environment/.env . && react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider start",
    "build": "cp environment/.env.production .env && react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider build && cp httpd_conf/.htaccess build/",
    "buildAndDeploy": "cp environment/.env.production .env && react-scripts build && cp httpd_conf/.htaccess build/ && /vagrant/frontend/publicar",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "prettier": "^2.0.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I replicated a simplified version of your project and everything works fine

This error make no sense, try deleting your `node_modules` and your `package-lock.json`

Then, install all your packages again:

```bash
npm install
```

If this doesn't work, seeing what's inside your `package.json` would be very helpful

Comment: Did that... same thing.

Comment: Edited the question with the package.json file

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add a crucial information on the first version of the question. This error is reported IN ECLIPSE ONLY. The compilation occurs normally